# How does gson maps json with POJO where json key has 2 space separated words

Tags: json, parsing, gson

I have a yelp dataset in json format. I am using gson to map to POJOs. However, some keys like  `"Drive-Thru", "Good For"` are hyphen or space separated. How to map POJO classes for these types of keys?

```
{
    "business_id":"5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANhGckJw",
    "attributes":{
        "Take-out":true,
        "Drive-Thru":false,
        "Good For":{
            "dessert":false,
            "latenight":false
        },
        "Caters":false,
        "Noise Level":"average",
        "Has TV":false,
        "Good For Groups":true,
        "Wi-Fi":"free",
        "Price Range":1
    },
    "type":"business"
}
```

I have following pojo but this returns me null for special key types

```
public class BusinessPojo {    
   private String type;
   private String business_id;
   private BusinessAttributes attributes;
// getters and setters
}

public class BusinessAttributes {
    private boolean takeOut;
    private boolean driveThru;
    private boolean Caters;
    private String noiseLevel;
    private boolean hasTV;
    private String wiFi;
    private boolean goodforGroups;
    private int priceRange;
    private BusinessGoodFor goodFor;
//getters and setters
}

public class BusinessGoodFor {
    private boolean dessert;
    private boolean latenight;
//getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gson provides a "serialized name" annotation:

```
public class BusinessAttributes {

  @SerializedName("Take-out")
  private boolean takeOut;
```

etc...